# Encoding issue python 2.7

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, keystone

I'm facing an issue since yesterday. I try to authenticate my openstack users on Active Directory. Keystone gets well the DN from AD. But when he wants to use it to check user's password it's not working because the DN contains "é".

You will find below my "print code":

```
    if isinstance(unistring, unicode):
        print("PRINT: START")
        print ["PRINT:"+_c for _c in unistring]
        print ("PRINT: type unistring  {}".format(type(unistring)))
        print ("PRINT: repr unistring  {}".format(repr(unistring)))
        print ("PRINT: utf8 unistring  {}".format(unistring.encode('utf8')))
        print ("PRINT: iso-8859-1 unistring  {}".format(unistring.encode('iso-8859-1')))
        print("PRINT: END")
```

This code will provide this output:

```
2017-10-31 18:56:51.701803 PRINT: START
2017-10-31 18:56:51.701862 [ u'PRINT:D', u'PRINT:\\xe9', uPRINT:p', u'PRINT:a', u'PRINT:r', u'PRINT:t', u'PRINT:e', u'PRINT:m', u'PRINT:e', u'PRINT:n', u'PRINT:t']
2017-10-31 18:56:51.701886 PRINT: type unistring  <type 'unicode'>
2017-10-31 18:56:51.701894 PRINT: repr unistring  u'=D\\xe9partement'
2017-10-31 18:56:51.701903 PRINT: utf8 unistring D\xc3\xa9partement 
2017-10-31 18:56:51.701943 PRINT: iso-8859-1 unistring  D\xe9partement
2017-10-31 18:56:51.701950 PRINT: END
```

I read/tried a lot of stuff on the internet but I still didnt figure out... Could you help?

Best regards,

Comment: Where's the LDAP stuff?

Comment: What's the problem you're having? (Did you expect this code to do something different from what it's doing? If so, what did you expect it to do?)

Comment: I want my code to display "Département" because my DN contains "Département"

Comment: Did you try printing it?

Comment: `unistring` does not currently have `Département` in it. It currently has `=D\xe9partement` in it (represented in Python code as `u'=D\\xe9partement'`). It's hard to suggest a "fix" since I don't know where `unistring` came from. Perhaps the bug is wherever you assigned that variable in the first place.

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder. But I strongly recommend you migrate to Python 3, which has much saner Unicode handling.

Comment: @smarx is right. The line came from AD answer the weird thing is unistring is unicode but AD encodes with utf-8

Comment: The output does not agree with the code provided.  In the `repr` case `unistring` starts with leading `=`, but the output of other lines does not (not to mention where is the timestamp coming from).  Provide **actual** code and **actual** output.  It is unclear what the **real** value of `unistring` is, and there is no possible value that agrees with the current output.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. Check again `repr(unistring)` - are you sure it starts with `=`?

Comment: Yes like I said it's a DN, i forgot to remove the = in some lines. The timestamps comes from Keystone. Anyway I think the problem is  i have this ```\\xe9``` instead of ```\xe9``` isnt?

Answer (score 1):

I think print(unistring) should just work. I tried the following in jupyter/scipy-notebook:

```
ustring = '使用電腦應該是人人必備技能，不過在日本卻出現了一個'
print(ustring)
```

And the output is correct.

Comment: The OP is using Python 2.7

Comment: ython 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ustring = u'Département'
>>> print ustring
Département
>>> ustring = u'使用電腦應該是人人必備技能，不過在日本卻出現了一個'
>>> print ustring
使用電腦應該是人人必備技能，不過在日本卻出現了一個
>>>
Didn't see any issue on my side...